# Confirm that the <usingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, msbuild-task

I have downloaded the project from SVN and trying to run the project and when I run it I get the below error. I tried installing .Net frameworks and changing the version of .csproj file but it didnt work. Please help me

[image: Error.]

Visual Studio details:
[image: Visual Studio details]
csproj contents, the content was too long so I have cut it to make it short.. Thanks in advance :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{6266E944-1458-4CF0-B1AC-F4AED6E6C330}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <RootNamespace>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Bootstrapper</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Bootstrapper</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{60dc8134-eba5-43b8-bcc9-bb4bc16c2548};{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <Reference Include="DotNetty.Buffers, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc13ca065fa06c29, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetty.Buffers.0.5.0\lib\net45\DotNetty.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetty.Codecs, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc13ca065fa06c29, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetty.Codecs.0.5.0\lib\net45\DotNetty.Codecs.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetty.Common, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc13ca065fa06c29, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetty.Common.0.5.0\lib\net45\DotNetty.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetty.Handlers, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc13ca065fa06c29, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetty.Handlers.0.5.0\lib\net45\DotNetty.Handlers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="DotNetty.Transport, Version=0.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bc13ca065fa06c29, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\DotNetty.Transport.0.5.0\lib\net45\DotNetty.Transport.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Options, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.2.2.0\lib\netstandard2.0\Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Common.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.6.0.1304.0\lib\NET45\Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\CommonServiceLocator.1.3\lib\portable-net4+sl5+netcore45+wpa81+wp8\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6d32ff45e0ccc69f, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Unity.4.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Practices.Unity.RegistrationByConvention.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ReportViewer.11.0.3366.16\lib\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.DLL</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.14.0.314.76\lib\net40\Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Win32.Primitives, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="MohammadDayyanCalendar">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\VTM Libs\VTM Libs\MohammadDayyanCalendar.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.AppContext, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.AppContext.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.AppContext.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Buffers, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Buffers.4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Buffers.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Collections.Immutable, Version=1.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Collections.Immutable.1.3.1\lib\portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81\System.Collections.Immutable.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.4.5.0\lib\net461\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.Composition" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Console, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Console.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Console.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Globalization.Calendars, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Globalization.Calendars.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.IO.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression, Version=4.1.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.Compression.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" />
    <Reference Include="System.IO.Compression.ZipFile, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO.FileSystem, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.FileSystem.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.FileSystem.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives, Version=4.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Memory.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Memory.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Http.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Net.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Sockets, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Net.Sockets.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Net.Sockets.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
    <Reference Include="System.Numerics.Vectors, Version=4.1.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Numerics.Vectors.4.4.0\lib\net46\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Reflection, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Reflection.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Reflection.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.4.5.1\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.Extensions.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.4.3.0\lib\net462\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.4.3.0\lib\net45\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.4.3.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.4.3.0\lib\net461\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions, Version=4.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.4.4.0\lib\netstandard2.0\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    <Reference Include="System.Windows.Interactivity">
      <HintPath>..\..\..\VTM Libs\Libraries\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
      <RequiredTargetFramework>4.0</RequiredTargetFramework>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml.ReaderWriter, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.4.3.0\lib\net46\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="WindowsBase" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationCore" />
    <Reference Include="PresentationFramework" />
    <Reference Include="WindowsFormsIntegration" />
    <Reference Include="XamlAnimatedGif, Version=1.1.10.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\XamlAnimatedGif.1.1.10\lib\net45\XamlAnimatedGif.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ApplicationDefinition Include="App.xaml">
      <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      <SubType>Designer</SubType>
    </ApplicationDefinition>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
      <DependentUpon>Resources.ar-AE.resx</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="SqlServerTypes\Loader.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedCreditCardStandbyViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedDebitCardStandbyViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedDocumentsViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedEnquiryViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedOffUsStandbyViewModel.cs" />
    <Compile Include="ViewModels\Authentication\AuthenticatedRTStandbyViewModel.cs" />
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{A1099D06-6C3F-4EB8-8097-709B178E6B32}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal\Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal.csproj">
      <Project>{ff7f2721-761f-4d37-8e82-e434168de720}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Client.Journal</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.Shell\Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.Shell.csproj">
      <Project>{c4e05b84-023e-4957-afcc-136038784894}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.Shell</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.UI.Themes\Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.UI.Themes.csproj">
      <Project>{b6d2823a-5d87-44c4-9d13-8a83f2e5ad48}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Supervisor.UI.Themes</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Bootstrapper.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Bootstrapper.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{05ef90b7-8b67-48b6-9fd8-e3bb39296807}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Bootstrapper.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{8e9fb737-ca04-4821-bc89-ae4fcbca3e2f}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication.csproj">
      <Project>{cd54b361-f8a1-414b-89aa-43c89d3dc7ca}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Communication</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{f5e2ca67-7440-44cd-bcaf-8f4068699663}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess.csproj">
      <Project>{82788099-841a-4a82-8800-3f0d15326bca}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.DataAccess</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{81c8ec3b-b030-4a57-bb0f-0f52f099a3ca}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices.csproj">
      <Project>{000cf3f2-33b0-4563-aad9-41a27c7353d1}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Devices</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{2f83688e-bf17-4e7a-9ee2-222f6136fbbc}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework.csproj">
      <Project>{8da717d8-8d26-4a89-954b-d7489fa73565}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Framework</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{a5802672-f8cb-490f-8566-02bfb616a0a3}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNDC.Interface\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNdc.Interface.csproj">
      <Project>{0827cc3b-9117-4cf4-8700-60662b1a3874}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNdc.Interface</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNDC\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNdc.csproj">
      <Project>{0068e8cd-518f-4ef2-90a0-04ad40e80d53}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.ServicesNdc</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services.csproj">
      <Project>{87c5641c-4830-44e9-890b-5d9f79e0f304}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Services</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Workflow\Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Workflow.csproj">
      <Project>{c47dc6b7-9b1d-4479-9509-cc75c4d8e366}</Project>
      <Name>Omnia.Pie.Vtm.Workflow</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Resource Include="Resources\Images\error.png" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="ViewModels\Billers\" />
    <Folder Include="Views\Billers\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="AfterCompile" Condition="exists('App.$(Configuration).config')">
    <!-- Generate transformed app config in the intermediate directory -->
    <TransformXml Source="App.config" Destination="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config" Transform="App.$(Configuration).config" />
    <!-- Force build process to use the transformed configuration file from now on. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Remove="App.config" />
      <AppConfigWithTargetPath Include="$(IntermediateOutputPath)$(TargetFileName).config">
        <TargetPath>$(TargetFileName).config</TargetPath>
      </AppConfigWithTargetPath>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" />
  <Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.3.0.61\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.SlowCheetah.targets'))" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

Comment: what version of VS are you on?

Comment: please post the xml content of the `*.csproj`

Comment: @JohnB its 2017... Please check my update...

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you on? (assuming you're using it)

Comment: @JohnB its 2017... I have added the visual studio details in the update ,please check.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that path to Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll is correct:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
```

You may also need to start the VS installer, to ensure you have Asp.net and web development tools.

Comment: I dont have a Web Folder on this path ( C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\SQL\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0)... what do you suggest ?

Comment: there's your problem - start the VS installer, to ensure you have Asp.net and web development tools.

Comment: I have web development build tools installed and also .Net desktop build tools installed. what else do I need ?

Comment: search your pc for `Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll`